# windows integrated security user.identity.isauthenticated returns false

Tags: security, iis

I swapped my hard disk for an ssd, and am having fun recreating my environment.
Im runnin win7 pro, and my web app is returning false from user.identity.isauthentication (was working fine before I upgraded to the ssd). 
I added windows integrated security as a security feature under the windows components (Im running local iis), and enabled it for the web site.
If I disable anonymous, user.identity.isauthenticated returns true with the correct credentials - BUT I am always prompted to enter my credentials.
AHAH - it must be ntfs permissions.  But Ive added them for every account I can think of - NETWORK SERVICES, my own account, IUSR, authentication users, and several others that were already there. Makes no difference.
Maybe the app pool Im running under - but Ive tried DefaultAppPool, .NET 4.0, and .NET 4.0 Classic.  Again, makes no difference.
Does anyone have any ideas on other things I can try? Im not on a domain or anything like that, this is entirely local.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in your web.config?

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

Comment: Good catch. However, it didnt work, and I tried different app pools and reviewed the ntfs settings. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in the browser, in this case under ie9 Internet Options. After verifying in the Advanced tab that Enable Windows Integrated Authentication was checked, one must go to the Security tab, under Local Intranet/Sites and uncheck "automatically detect intranet network" and check "include all local intranet sites".